# Notepad++ Macro to open specific file

Tags: macros, notepad++

How can I create a macro in Notepad++ to open a specific file (for example C:\Users\ega\all.txt) ?

Comment: Have the same question, too.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a Macro I used 'Run' and browsed the file and added a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

the question has sense: perhaps one would need firstly to open a specific file, then to operate with it and save operations in a single macro

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).